# JWT Token Storage

Tags: security, .net-core, jwt

I have been going through some of my .NET Core2 services and adding some JWT authentication to them to provide some basic security.

I created a new `ProvisioningService` which has an endpoint that builds a token and returns it:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        signingCredentials: creds);

return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

I altered one of my existing services (which I'll refer to as `TestService`) by adding `AddAuthentication` in the `StartUp`.  The endpoint for this call has the `[HttpPost(), Authorize]` attributes.  I deployed these changes to my Test server.

When I call `TestService/api/updateSomething` I am returned a `401 Unauthorized` as expected.  On my local machine, I create a new token via `ProvisioningService/api/buildToken` and add the token from the response to my `TestService` call via the Authorization header.  To my surprise...this worked.

Why does my `TestService` (on a completely different server) view a token created on my local machine as a valid token and allow the call to work?  I was expecting this to return the same `401` because I assumed this token was going to be invalid on my Test server.  My inexperience with JWT is probably showing....but I am not understanding how these tokens are being stored/shared between servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to understand that the token itself has what it needs to authorize itself after it is decrypted.  This question is no longer needed.